# PostgreSQL calculated column not displaying numbers after decimal and rounding value to 0

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, decimal, numeric

I'm trying to perform a following calculation in a query:

```
t0.value1::decimal * 10 ^ (-1 * t2.value2::decimal) * t0.value3::decimal as total_value
```

However since `(-1 * t2.value2::decimal)` returns -18 all the results are rounding up to 0. I tried explicitly stating decimal scale and precision//changing it to numeric but got the same output.
It works just fine as long as `(-1 * t2.value2::decimal)` is **more than -10 and less than 10 (if the number of decimals is less than 10)**.

How can it be solved?

UPD: here is the data sample

| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4600000000000000000 | 18 | 4631.012195988508 |
| 5000000000000000000 | 18 | 3273.4212494812623 |
|  |  |  |
|  | 18 | 2422.052197425213 |
| 25000000000000000000 | 18 | 2549.800132829858 |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
| 9690000000000000000 | 18 | 4109.547860742057 |
| 5980000000000000000 | 18 | 2957.913800830533 |
| 4200000000000000000 | 18 | 3410.6366004760075 |
| 8000000000000000000 | 18 | 3902.894047163281 |
|  |  |  |
| 6000000000000000000 | 18 | 4604.587023538565 |

Comment: can you supply some values?

Comment: -18 < 10 yet it does not work according to your description. I can't replicate: `select 10^(-18); 1e-18`. You will need to provide some actual example input data and output data.

Comment: @DannySlor added some values, please take a look

Comment: @AdrianKlaver updated the description & provided some sample input data, pls take a look

Comment: The issue seems to be here `(-1 * t2.value2::decimal)` change that to `(-1 * t2.value2)` and it goes away. Not sure why yet. What version of Postgres?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it works for me if value2 is int and doesn't work if value2 is numeric.

Comment: Well if you look here [Math](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-math.html) the exponent is taken to be either `numeric` or `double precision`. At any rate I have posted to postgres-general mailing list to get guidance.

Comment: For those who are interested you can follow this [Exponentiation confusion](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/12a40226-70ac-3a3b-3d3a-fdaf9e32d312%40aklaver.com) thread on the pgsql-general mailing list. Seems there is a bug in play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 is interpreted as a decimal with scale 20. Give it higher precision and scale:

```
t0.value1::decimal * 10::decimal(40,20) ^ (-1 * t2.value2::decimal) * t0.value3::decimal as total_value
```

This behavior was considered a bug by PostgreSQL development and has been fixed in [this commit](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=40c7fcbbed5d922e905f8032c5035826d0406980) in PostgreSQL v16. The fix will not be applied to older versions, to avoid "the risk of changing query
results in stable branches".

Answer (score 0):

`x^(-y) = 1/x^y` and that works.

```
select value1::decimal * (1/10 ^(value2::decimal)) * value3::decimal as total_value
from   t
```

| total_value |
| --- |
| 21302.656101547136800000000000000000000000000000000000 |
| 16367.1062474063115000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
| 63745.003320746450000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
| 39821.518770590532330000000000000000000000000000000000 |
| 17688.324528966587340000000000000000000000000000000000 |
| 14324.6737219992315000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
| 31223.152377306248000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
| 27627.522141231390000000000000000000000000000000000000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-XZbBqEt)